# Perl File::Fetch failed because the URL doesn't have a file part

Tags: perl, download

I am running a script that pulls URLs from a database and performs a file::fetch(). From my understanding, file::fetch() only works when there is really a file in the URL to be downloaded.

However, in my database there is the occasional URL where there is no file to be fetched. So, is there any module I can use to check that there is a file in the URL I am attempting to perform a file::fetch()?

There is a line in my script

```
my $uri_handle = File::Fetch->new(uri => $url);
```

where the $url may be something like `http://asiaone.com` with no file to actually be fetched.

And I get this error which I am desperately trying to avoid because there are other URLs that mostly contain files to fetch.

```
Use of uninitialized value $path in pattern match (m//) at C:/Perl/lib/File/Spec/Unix.pm line 267.
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at C:/Perl/lib/File/Fetch.pm line 395.
Hostname required when fetching from 'http' at C:\test\multihashtest2.pl line 100 thread 2
```

How can I format my regular expression to check for files or is there a module I can use to facilitate this?

A legitimate URL would be something like below

```
http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/puttytel.exe
```

Comment: how does a valid url looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [manual of File::Fetch](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/File-Fetch-0.36/lib/File/Fetch.pm) there is this flag, [$File::Fetch::WARN](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/File-Fetch-0.36/lib/File/Fetch.pm#$File::Fetch::WARN), which you can set to `false` in order to silence the errors:

> This variable controls whether errors encountered internally by
>   File::Fetch should be carp'd or not.
>
> Set to false to silence warnings. Inspect the output of the error()
>   method manually to see what went wrong.
>
> Defaults to true.

Comment: How do i apply that option to false?

Comment: try with `$File::Fetch::WARN = 0;`

Comment: The same error still appears after i apply that line of code. It only removes the `Hostname required when fetching from 'http' at C:\test\multihashtest2.pl line 100 thread 2 ` error from the output. The other two errors stating uninitialized values still remain.

Comment: try adding an `eval{}` around the fetch like `my $uri_handle; eval { $uri_handle = File::Fetch->new(uri => $url); }`. This will silence all the errors :)